# Concatenate several variables does not work inside iterations and works outside of iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate several variables and calculate the sum and since I want to do multiple operations, I am iterating through all the possible combinations of variables which are already saved in the df.cols but I get key error.

```
for i in df.cols[0:20]: 
    k+=1
    name = "cat" + str(k)
    df1[name] = df1.loc[:, i].sum(axis = 1)
```

It gives KeyError although it is in the columns.

```
KeyError: "the label [['D120_1', 'Y69_0', 'K189_0']] is not in the [columns]"
```

For example, when I try to print i:

```
print(i)
['D120_1', 'Y69_0', 'K189_0']
```

and when I try it without iteration replacing the i with ['D120_1', 'Y69_0', 'K189_0'] it works well. Why does it recognize the key inside iteration and does not recognize it outside the iteration.

This works well although the same thing as in the iteration.

```
df1["col1"] = df1.loc[:, ['D120_1', 'Y69_0', 'K189_0']].sum(axis = 1)
```

But this does not work:

```
df1["col1"] = df1.loc[:, i].sum(axis = 1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that i variable actually will be a List. Try df1[name] = df1.loc[:, list(i)].sum(axis = 1)

Answer (score 0):

If remember correctly in Pandas both start and stop index are included in the slice as opposed to how Python does it where the last index is skipped. See if that is the source of your problem - you may be iterating to an unavailable index(label).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I discovered that the list was saved as string "['D120_1', 'Y69_0', 'K189_0']"

To solve the problem I used [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
from ast import literal_eval
i = literal_eval(i)
print(i)
['D120_1', 'Y69_0', 'K189_0']
```